# Uncaught ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Expecting Unicode escape sequence

Tags: next.js, compiler-errors, proxy, dynamic-class-loaders

Good morning, I am trying to use a next 13 project and it returns the following error.

File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-flight-loader/index.js
- ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-swc-loader.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  | import { createProxy } from "next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-flight-loader/module-proxy"

> const proxy = createProxy(String.raw`C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Chino\App`s\custer proyectos\naimayer-services-nextjs\src\components\user\session\login\loginPage.tsx`)
> |
> | // Accessing the __esModule property and exporting $$typeof are required here.

The error is returned in the components where the 'use client' is used

I already tried updating the version of next on my computer and the project.